# Hyper-V to VirtualBox with Guest Applications

Tags: centos, virtualbox, hyper-v

I have converted a CentOS 7.2 Hyper-V VHDX instance to a VirtualBox 5.1.10 VDI instance using the VBoxManage clone command and am using this VirtualBox instance on a Mac. Everything works well except the guest instance will not run in full screen mode. I have tried to install Guest Applications but it fails each time.
Is there anything that I am missing in this process?

Comment: Did you mount your Virtual Box Guest Additions iso?

Comment: Whats the failure? Can you paste the message?